# Highest row, based on three columns, per group

Tags: sql-server

```
Type  major  minor  build  module
----  -----  -----  -----  -----
290   0      0      1      Name1
290   1      0      1      Name1
290   1      0      2      Name1
300   0      0      1      Name2
300   2      0      1      Name2
300   2      1      1      Name2
```

I have been trying to get a query to show only the rows with the highest version, per type, based on the three columns (major.minor.build). The module name will replace the module type.

Based on the sample data the results should be:

```
Type    major    minor    build    module
----    -----    -----    -----    ------
290     1        0        2        Name1
300     2        1        1        Name2
```

Comment: The problem is getting the highest for each type.

Answer (score 4):

To obtain highest for each type, you can query e.g. like:

```
;with cte as (
    select Type, major, minor, build, module
        rn = row_number() over (partition by Type 
          order by major desc, minor desc, build desc)
    from TableName
)
select Type, major, minor, build, module
from cte
where rn=1
```

Comment: Should there be another parentheses at the end of line three?

Comment: @mythago.wolf yes, corrected. This is one of the risks of not bothering to use proper carriage returns and avoid horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @mythago.wolf, right, it seems I didn't followed rule _type both brackets at once, and then type between_. Thank you Aaron for correction.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable ORDER BY major DESC, minor DESC, build DESC
```

Comment: +1 to this, since _for each type_ was added later